# asp.net core ef order by doesn't work after declaration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

The following will order results by address inside my view :

```
var results = _context.SiteUnit.OrderBy(x=>x.address);
return View(await results.ToListAsync());
```

However, writing it this way does not order the results in my view:

```
var results = _context.SiteUnit;
results.OrderBy(x=>x.address);
return View(await results.ToListAsync());
```

Has anyone experienced this? I am trying to solve this issue because I need to set the OrderBy clause afterwords, based on a selected filter.

Comment: Try `results = results.OrderBy(x=>x.address)`.  Also take a look at [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution presented by Mark G, which worked for me.

```
results = results.OrderBy(x=>x.address)
```